# Spring JMSTemplate with ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I'm working on a JMS intensive application that sends/receives hundreds of thousands of messages. I found that performance wasn't all that great and narrowed down the issue to 1 line like below, root cause from what I can tell is it doesn't play well with IBM MQ.

```
JMSTemplate.receive(queueName);
```

After wrapping this code in a simple timer, I found that receive was taking anywhere from 20-50 milliseconds and due to the sheer amount of throughput I'm dealing with that will surely add up over time. After a bit of googling I stumbled upon springs "CachingConnectionFactory", which I implemented with blind luck like below (wasn't sure if this would have worked with IBM MQ Connection factory that I was already using). Note that some code is omitted for legibility...

```
    <bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        ...
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <ref bean="cacheFactory" />
        </property>
        ...
    </bean>

    <!--This seems to be the magic piece-->
    <bean id="cacheFactory"
        class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="ibmMQConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="100" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="ibmMQConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
        ...
    </bean>
```

To my surprise, this cut down my JMSTemplate.receive() calls from anywhere between 20-50+ milliseconds to about 1-2 millis per message. I'm not able to find any solid information about how exactly this works behind the scenes and how "sessionCacheSize" will affect performance. My first test I used a value of 50 and the second time 100, with the second option proving much faster. So my question is, what is an ideal "sessionCacheSize" for an application with a massive amount of throughput, and what are any drawbacks to consider with this approach?

I look forward to what you guys have to say on this one...

Answer (score 0):

My knowledge on Spring is limited. But by reading you description, I believe Spring is doing the following every time for receiving a message:

1) Creating a connection to IBM MQ Queue Manager

2) Opening specified queue

3) Getting message from queue

4) Closing the queue

5) Closing the connection.

Because of all the above operations, the time taken to receive single message is more. But when session is cached, Spring is re-using a cached connection. Hence better message receive throughput.